# How to freeze a layer in After Effects using Extendscript language?

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I already have some compositions inside an array.

```
    x = *is an item inside an array* .. 
    y = 1 ; // just one layer in this comp.

    myLayer = app.project.item(x).layer(y)
```

what i need is to apply a command to freeze this layer... 
searched many places and still couldnt find it yet...

Anyone could help?

Comment: This is a better fit for videoproduction.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add time-remapping to the layer in question:

```
myLayer= app.project.item(x).layer(y);
myLayer.timeRemapEnabled = true;
timeRemap = mylayer.property("Time Remap");
timeRemap.setValueAtTime(theTime , theValue); // or is it (theValue, theTime)?
```

Time remapping is a property of the Layer object in AE.

Comment: till there, im ok.. but theres no "freeze" parameter?
it's a "manual" mode of freezing, but automatically?

Comment: Just set a single keyframe. That's what `SetValueAtTime()` does to any property. If you want the motion to proceed normally up to the freeze set two keyframes, one at the layer in-point and one at the freeze point. You may also have to extend the layer's outpoint if the freeze extends past the natural duration of the clip.

Comment: Just in case: myLayer.locked = true;

Comment: @Xavier that just locks the layer, I don't see the connection.

Comment: It was in case there was a misunderstanding on the word "freeze".
If your suggestion is correct, this question is more about a freeze technique in After Effects than a coding issue.